# Git Integration to The Bug Genie?

Tags: git, version-control, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

I've set up the bug tracker [The Bug Genie](http://thebuggenie.com/) for use in one of my developer groups and so far, most things have been pretty easy to get working. Now, I'd like to make use of their Git integration. However, their documentation seems a bit lacking and seems to assume I know some things that I evidently don't.

Does anyone know of some good resources for setting up Git integration into Bug Genie? I have a Linux-based server that I have full control over, so I'm not really limited in that aspect, and I can use the hooks that Bug Genie comes with. I just need some more guidance for getting everything working.

I found the hook that they've provided, but it doesn't really give me enough information to feel comfortable going off of in my current server setup (which uses Capistrano for some stuff, and has some post-receive hooks already). I was hoping for something a little clearer (even some clarification on the documentation already there) so I don't have to resort to trial and error.

Comment: any update? does Zsub answer help?

Comment: @CharlesB - I don't know yet. I haven't had time to try. It looks like it will help, but I still need to actually try. Thanks for adding the Bug Genie tag, BTW. I don't have the rep to do that yet. =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a hook script under `$buggeniedir/modules/vcs_integration/hooks/git`, it's pretty much self-documenting.

Mind you, you'll have to manually add it to every repository, unfortunately.

Edit:

You copy the hook file from `$buggeniedir/modules/vcs_integration/hooks/git/tbg-post-receive` to `$your-repo-dir/.git/hooks/post-receive` (on the server!). Then you edit the post-receive file you just copied in to contain the full path to the installation directory of Bug Genie (mind you, the directory!). After that set the appropriate ID in the hook-file. You can find that ID in the Bug Genie webinterface, at `yourbugenieurl.com/configure/module/vcs_integration`, click on Project Settings (the help page that that page links to contains all keywords, as well).

Clone/update the repo from the server, change something, voila :)

Comment: I know the hook is there, but in my opinion, it's not self-documenting (at least not enough for me to understand it well enough to be comfortable). Hence the request for more resources.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It looks like it should be useful. Now I just need the time to actually try it!

Comment: I had a chance to look at it some more. One of the things I think that confused me is that there is an option for "direct access" as well as "http access." Direct access, to me would suggest that I wouldn't need cgit/gitweb to make use of it, but the way the Wiki is written, it suggests that I do. Which way is correct? The repos and the tracker are hosted on the same machine, and both are private, so I would prefer direct access if possible.

Comment: You can do direct access by calling tbg-cli or something. We actually switched to Redmine here, so I wouldn't really know I'm afraid.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I'm attempting the same thing right now

Comment: I followed this manual precisely and even though I haven't been able to get this working. The problem was that my post-recieve file didn't have access rights set correctly, so it couldn't be executed by Git. After I set it to 777 it started working. Also, you have to set access righst to 777 for file tbg_cli in bug genie installation folder. Hope this helps!